# Nearest neighbour queries. Postgis vs neo4j spatial

Tags: database, neo4j, gis, postgis, neo4j-spatial

Im building an application which will be making queries like 'give me the nearest 10 points to this location ordered by proximity' what database is more performant in making these types of queries?

Much appreciated if you have some performance numbers too,

Comment: They both support a "Within Distance" / "ST_DWithin" using a spatial index, so they probably have similar performances. Start with whichever you are most familiar with. PostGIS is the most mature of the two, so it should have the most stable features.